# Is it possible to create a layout template for components using SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I would like to create a modal template inside `$lib`, but it looks like you can only create a `_layout.svelte` inside `src/routes`. Is there a standard practice for creating layouts for components?

For example, if I had to several modal components structured like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        [Content Goes Here]
    </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking it would be easier to make a `_layout.svelte` like this

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <slot />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, when I want to make a specific type of modal, I can reference the `_layout.svelte` so I can focus on content itself. This would be the content to replace `<slot />`:

```
<h1>
    Content Goes Here
</h1>
```

Comment: `_layout.svelte` is for full pages, that probably is not what you need anyway. You might want to elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @H.B. Great idea, I just updated my post.

Comment: My answer still stands, you simply create a component with the slot, import that where you want to use it and insert the content inside of it. Added example code to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modal template can be any component with a [`<slot/>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-slot), layouts are for pages.

Given the example:

```html
<!-- Modal.svelte -->
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <slot />
    </div>
</div>
```

In some other part of the application:

```html
<script>
  import Modal from '$lib/Modal.svelte';
</script>

<Modal>
  <h1>...</h1>
</Modal>
```

Comment: I don't know why my mind was drawing a blank, this is such a fundamental part of Svelte components. Thank you.